# Intellisense is not working since upgrade to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, intellisense

We recently upgraded our production server to SQL Server 2014. This server hosts ~2200 databases. When I connect to it as `sa` with SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and I type queries, Intellisense does not work (nothing show up). Before the upgrade, we ran SQL Server 2008 and SSMS 2008 and Intellisense was working perfectly in the same conditions. Also, Intellisense works when connected to an other server (our development server, SQL 2014 too) which holds ~10 databases.

- I already made sure Intellisense is enabled
- I already tried to Refresh the local cache (CTRL-Shift-R)

Am I missing something else? Or does it have something to do with the number of databases on the server? If so, why was that not happening before, with SQL Server 2008?

Comment: If you type `dbo.` and then just wait, does a list *eventually* show up? Give it time. It may be a connectivity issue. Also see [this tip](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/) for other potential ideas (it's labeled as 2012-specific but it's really not).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm a little ashamed... SQL Server 2014 SP1 was not installed on my client machine. Doing so seems to fix the problem with SSMS Intellisense.

Comment: Client tools should always be >= version/SP of the highest server you manage.

Comment: SP1 is not installed the server yet, we will do it soon.